# Simplify recurrence $\frac{d}{dx} f_{n-1}(x)= f_n(x)- f_{n-1}(x) f_1(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, recurrence-relations

Suppose we have a sequence of infinitely differentiable functions $ \{ f_k(x) \}$.   Now suppose that these functions satisfy the following recursion:
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx} f_{n-1}(x)= f_n(x)-  f_{n-1}(x) f_1(x)
\end{align}

where $f_0(x)=1$ for all $x$.  Can we re-write $f_n(x)$ only in terms of $f_1(x)$ and derivatives of $f_1(x)$?

It is not difficult to see that this is possible. The difficulty is to create the exact formula.

Comment: Is the recursion $\frac{d}{dx} f_{n+1}(x)= f_n(x)-  f_{n-1}(x) f_1(x)$?

Comment: @xpaul No, it with $n-1$ for the derivative.  Why? Does that equation have a known form?

Comment: It comes from Faa di Bruno's formula and complete Bell polynomials. See the  [OEIS sequence A036040](https://oeis.org/A036040) and the very similar [OEIS sequence A080575](https://oeis.org/A080575) for much more details.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{d}{dx}f_{n-1}(x)=f_n(x)-f_{n-1}(x)f_1(x),\ \ \ \ f_0(x)=1$$

$$f_n(x)=\frac{d}{dx}f_{n-1}(x)+f_{n-1}(x)f_1(x)$$
$\ $

$$f_1(x)=\frac{d}{dx}f_0(x)+f_0(x)f_1(x)=f_1(x)$$

$$f_2(x)=\frac{d}{dx}f_1(x)+f_1(x)f_1(x)$$

$$f_3(x)=\frac{d}{dx}f_2(x)+f_2(x)f_1(x)$$

$$...$$
$\ $

$f_n(x)$ is the following special complete exponential [Bell polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials):

$$f_n(x)=B_n(f_1^{(0)}(x),f_1^{(1)}(x),...,f_1^{(n-1)}(x))=\sum_{\sum_{t=1}^{n}tk_t=n}\frac{n!}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}i!^{k_{i}}k_{i}!}\prod_{i=1}^{n}{f_1^{(i-1)}(x)}^{k_{i}}$$

The vectors of running indices $(k_1,...,k_n)$ in the sum expression represent the integer partitions of $n$.

Applying [Faà di Bruno's Formula (Higher chain rule)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula), we get:

$$f_n(x)=e^{-\int f_1(x)dx}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{\int f_1(x)dx}=e^{-\int f_1(x)dx}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left(f_1(x)e^{\int f_1(x)dx}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks.  Can you add more details about how you arrived at the exponential Bell polynomial answer?  Specifically, at what point do you see that it an exponential Bell polynomial.

Comment: I saw this on the coefficients. "Higher derivatives are set-partitions". But you can prove it by verifying the concluded integral formula and applying Faà di Bruno's formula to it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is what you want. It is easy to see
$$f_n(x) = f_{n-1}^\prime(x) + f_{n-1}(x)f_1(x). \tag{1}$$
Multiplying both sides of (1) by $e^{\int f_1(x)dx}$ gives
$$f_n(x)e^{\int f_1(x)dx} = \bigg[f_{n-1}(x) e^{\int f_1(x)dx}\bigg]'. \tag{2}$$
Let
$$ g_n(x)=f_n(x)e^{\int f_1(x)dx}. $$
Then (2) gives
$$ g_n(x)=g_{n-1}'(x) $$
Using this recursion $(n-1)$-times, one has
$$ g_n(x)=g_1^{(n-1)}(x)=\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\bigg[f_1(x)e^{\int f_1(x)dx}\bigg] $$
and hence
$$ f_n(x)=e^{-\int f_1(x)dx}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\bigg[f_1(x)e^{\int f_1(x)dx}\bigg] $$

Comment: Can you clarify what are the limits of integration are?

Comment: It is simply the antiderivative, the indefinite integral.

Comment: @IV_   is it $\int_{-\infty}^x f(t) dt$?

Comment: @Lisa, you can simply use $\int_0^xf_1(t)dt$ instead of $\int f_1(x)dx$.

Comment: I have more question. From your proof, it seems like you have seen something similar before. Does this equation have a name?

Comment: I did not see similar questions before.